# Excel DATE() function crashes on big dataset

Tags: excel, performance, csv, date, optimization

I have a general data manipulation question and then a specific performance question with the DATE() function in Excel.

I have a large .csv file (1m rows) which comes to me in the following format:

| Client_Name | Client_ID | Transaction_Date | Subscription_Service | Subs_Concat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Blogs | 1234 | 13/01/2022 13:45 | Service1 | 1234_20220113_20220213_Service1 |
| John Doe | 5678 | 13/01/2022 07:45 | Service2 | 5678_20220113_20220213_Service1 |

My problem is with the Subs_Concat field - I basically need to strip out the two dates from the middle of the string and convert into Date format.

My first step is essentially doing Text-To-Columns and using the "_" character as the delimiter. This then gives me two strings, namely 20220113 and 20220213 if we take the first row of data as an example.

I then use the Excel DATE function as follows for the first of those strings ("20220113") which is in cell F2:

```
=DATE(LEFT(F2,4),MID(F2,4,2),RIGHT(F2,2))
```

Now my problem is that this seems to work for the first 300k or so rows, but then becomes wildly inaccurate. For example it has translated this: 20211206 to 06/11/2021 when actually it should be 06/12/2021. It has also translated 20220131 to this 31/08/2023.

I have checked the formula has dragged down properly and is referencing the right cells, it just doesnt seem to be returning the right results. I have of course tried recalculating and also closing down all Excels and then trying again.

My question here is two-fold:

1. Is there a better way for me to manipulate this field to get the dates I need?
2. Has anyone ever experienced this inaccuracy with the DATE() function on large datasets and if so, how did you fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MID(F2,5,2)`?

Comment: D'oh! Schoolboy error there... fixing that seems to have worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: A bit of a non sequitur, but have you considered a transition to python?  This is an easy python task without the fragility/cumbersomeness of dealing with 1M rows in Excel.  :)